# Apache Basic Auth seems to override File access restrictions set in .htaccess

Tags: basic-authentication

I have setup a virtual host with Basic Auth.

```
<Directory ~ "^/home/www/.*/">
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "HALMA"
            AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
            Require valid-user
            Allow from 10.0.0
            Satisfy Any
    </Directory>

    <Files ~ "\.(htaccess|inc|tpl)$">
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
    </Files>
```

( The Files Section could be in a .htaccess, too - same effect)

Now .htaccess, .inc and .tpl files are accessible if the user authenticates successfully to the Basic Auth, which is not the intended behavior. The file restrictions should always be active, preventing any user from accessing critical files, logged-in or not.

I tried moving the Files-Section from vhost config to .htaccess and vice versa, commenting out the 10.0.0.

If I comment out the whole Auth stuff it works.

Would be glad, if someone could point me in the right direction.